# 'program.opts()' is returning empty instead of showing me the options I've added to my command

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-commander

I'm trying to develop a cli utility in JavaScript & node.js that is similar to the sed command in Unix. I've made a command using the Commander library, that seeks for a word in a file and replaces it with another. I also need to add options to the command itself and, following Commander's documentation, I added said options. One of the options is '-n' which is supposed to prevent anything (Only the successful message for now) from being printed when you execute the command. However, I noticed that my validation wasn't working and it would still print the successful message. Eventually I found out that my validation wasn't working because the 'program.opts()' ('cmdr.opts()' in my code) is returning empty. According to the documentation, 'opts()' is where all the options that I add, should be and if I do console.log(program.opts()) I should get back an object with all the options as properties.

I've spent some time reading the documentation but I cannot find anything about it. I even asked ChatGPT and it said that my code was fine and it should work... So I'm not really sure of what I'm missing or not seeing.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Kind regards!

Code:

```
async function main() {

    cmdr
        .command('s <cmd> <file>')
        .description('Modifies a string, by first selecting a target file.')
        .option('-n, --negate', 'Prevents a line from being printed unless specified by "-p".')
        .option('-i', 'Forces sed to edit the file instead of printing to the standar output.')
        .option('-e', 'Accepts multiple substitution commands with one command per "-e" appearance.')
        .option('-f <file>', 'Expects a file which consists of several lines containing one command each.')
        .option('-p, --print', 'Prints the line on the terminal.')
        .option('-g', 'Substitutes all instances of the search.')
        .action(async(cmd, file) => {

            // Code logic...
        });

    cmdr.parseAsync(process.argv);

}

main();
```

I've tried to log the options in these ways:

```
                console.log(cmdr.opts());
                console.log(cmdr.negate);
                console.log(options.n);
                console.log(options.negate);
```

I've also tried to parse before the action, inside the action and using parseOptions() but to no avail.

The command needed to call the program is as follows:

```
node app.js s foo/bar file.txt -n
```

Comment: It is good practice to reduce your example to the minimum to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Also: please include an example of how you are calling the program. I assume for your case something like: `node index.js s -n foo bar`

Comment: I apologize for my mistakes and I will keep your advices into consideration for future posts. It is much appreciated. I've also edited the post to add the cli needed to call the program but for the sake of saving you time I'll add it here as well: node app.js s foo/bar file.txt -n

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the solution I came across. Once I moved the options to a separate cmdr everything worked as expected.

```
cmdr
        .command('s <cmd> <file>')
        .description('Modifies a string, by first selecting a target file.')
        .action(async(cmd, file) => { 
        // Code logic...
        });


cmdr
        .option('-n, --negate', 'Description')
        .option('-i, --instead', 'Description')
        .option('-e, --extra <extra...>', 'Description', [])
        .option('-f, --function <file>', 'Description')
        .option('-p, --print', 'Description')
        .option('-g, --global', 'Description')

    cmdr.parseAsync(process.argv);
```

Comment: What this does is put all the options on the root command instead of the s subcommand. Presumably you are accessing the options on `cmdr.opts()`? That will sort of work, but if you had another subcommand would you want all the same options or are they really just for the s subcommand?

Comment: Yes, they were intended for the s subcommand only. I chose this approach for the sake of getting the project finished. However, I'd like to learn how to properly use Commander as I do plan to use it in the future. If I understand correctly my solution only worked because the options are "globally" available in the root command? But if I try to add those options only for the s subcommand by adding them before the .action(), it wouldn't work. Would you know why that would be? Thank you very much for your replies, by the way!

Comment: See my answer for the expected way of accessing subcommand options. If you have more detailed questions, perhaps open an issue on Commander: https://github.com/tj/commander.js/issues

Answer (score 0):

Commander saves the options for a particular subcommand on that subcommand. They are not all saved on the root command/program.

The action handler is passed the options and the local command to make it convenient to access them. So your action handler could look like:

```
cmdr
   .command('s <cmd> <file>') // add subcommand called 's'
   .option('-n, --negate', 'Description')
   // ...
   .action(async(cmd, file, options, sCommand) => {
      // These two will log the same.
      console.log(options);
      console.log(sCommand.opts());
   });

cmdr.parseAsync(process.argv);
```

(Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of Commander.)

Comment: Hello shadowspawn, and thank you for your reply. I apologize for the late reply as well, I had a timeframe to deliver this project so I ended up finishing it and then forgetting about it. However, I found a solution that didn't make much sense to me but it worked nonetheless. Perhaps you could shed some light on it as I plan to continue using Commander. The solution consists on separating the options into a different cmdr as shown in my own reply below.

Comment: Reworked the example to make it match your sample program more closely and hopefully clearer.